# What is the best way to return agregate column with non agregate column in result set of a view

Tags: mysql, sql-server-2008, select, aggregate

I need to compare the final balances of two tables from different clients grouped by ID. The tables have the same ID's But one has multiple ID entries and the other does not. I need to sum row from the table with multiple entries so I have just one final number to do calculations with.

Table1:

```
ID,    cost,    traceNumber,   TheDate
1,     200,     1001,          10/07/2011
1,     -20,     1002,          10/08/2011
1,     130,     1003,          10/10/2011
2,     300,     1005,          10/10/2011
```

Table2:

```
ID,    cost
1,     200
2,     300
```

Result for ID 1, would be 310 compared to table2 of 200 with a difference of 110

The Query will look something like this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    Table1.ID,
    Table1.TheDate ,
    Table1.traceNumber,
    Table1.[cost] AS Frost_Balance, 
    SUM(Table1.[cost]) AS SUM_Frost_Balance, 
    Table2.[cost] AS Ternean_Balance, 
    SUM(Table1.[cost]) - Table2.[cost] AS Ending_Balance, 
FROM  
    Table1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ID =Table2.CustomerID 
GROUP BY 
    dbo.Frost.ID
```

The query has to display multiple columns in the result set because it is going to be used to report on. I tried grouping by all columns in the result set but that gave me wrong results. Is there another way to compute the column that needs to be summed up?

Comment: Is your question really for both SQL Server 2008 *and* MySQL? The latter seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
-- Data setup
CREATE TABLE [Table1]
(
    [ID] INT,
    [cost] INT,
    [traceNumber] INT,
    [TheDate] DATE
)

INSERT [Table1]
VALUES  (1, 200, 1001, '10/07/2011'),
        (1, -20, 1002, '10/08/2011'),
        (1, 130, 1003, '10/10/2011'),
        (2, 300, 1005, '10/10/2011')

CREATE TABLE [Table2]
(
    [ID] INT,
    [cost] INT
)

INSERT [Table2]
VALUES  (1, 200),
        (2, 300)

-- Query
;WITH [cteTable1Sum] AS
(
    SELECT [ID], SUM([cost]) AS [cost]
    FROM [Table1]
    GROUP BY [ID]
)       
SELECT  [Table1].[ID], 
        [Table1].[TheDate], 
        [Table1].[traceNumber],
        [Table1].[cost] AS [Frost_Balance],
        cte.[cost] AS [SUM_Frost_Balance],
        [Table2].[cost] AS [Ternean_Balance],
        cte.[cost] - [Table2].[cost] AS [Ending_Balance]
FROM [Table1]
INNER JOIN [Table2]
    ON [Table1].[ID] = [Table2].[ID]
INNER JOIN [cteTable1Sum] cte
    ON [Table1].[ID] = cte.[ID]
```

Comment: Man your awesome that is exactly what I was looking for, and thanks for the fast reply.
But could you please explain this piece of code
;WITH [cteTable1Sum] AS
(
    SELECT [ID], SUM([cost]) AS [cost]
    FROM [Table1]
    GROUP BY [ID]
)  

What is the ;WITH and how do you refer to as just cte in the select statement?
Thanks

Comment: [SQL Server 2008 - Using Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=SQL.100).aspx)

Comment: I can use just 'cte' because I created this as a table alias in the second INNER JOIN.  Read more here - [Using Table Aliases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187455(v=SQL.100).aspx).

Comment: How would I get this to group by month? This totals it for all dates. The data actually needs to be sorted by ID and by month so they know the endig monthly ballance for every ID. Is there a way to do this. 
;WITH [cteTable1Sum] AS
(
    SELECT [ID], SUM([cost]) AS [cost]
    FROM [Table1]
    GROUP BY [ID], [TheDate]
) 
This gives me the wrong answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "Window Aggregate Function" like this:

```
select 
    table1.*,
    sum(table1.cost) over (partition by table1.id) sum_frost_balance,
    table2.cost,
    sum(table1.cost) over (partition by table1.id) - table2.cost ending_balance
from table1
    join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```